# How does apache IOTDB query the time of the last change of data?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

In IoTDB, there are time series under root.device_id, where xxxx represents multiple series. I would like to query for the last changed value and the time of change under root.device_id. How should I write the query statement?
such as :1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3，i need find when data change from 2 to 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Apache IoTDB, you can use `diff` or `change_points` function to implement your requirement.

Here is the example sqls:

```
CREATE TIMESERIES root.db.d1.s1 INT32;
INSERT INTO root.db.d1(timestamp,s1) values(1,1),(2,2),(3,2),(4,3),(5,3),(6,3),(7,3),(8,3),(9,3);
select s1 from root.db.d1 where diff(s1) != 0 limit 2;
select max_time(s1), last_value(s1) from root.db.d1 where diff(s1) != 0;
select change_points(s1) from root.db.d1;
select change_points(s1) from root.db.d1 order by time desc limit 2;
```

Here is the running results:
[image: running results]

[image: change_points]